# Root user folder permissions changed in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: file-permissions, ubuntu-14.04, private-key, gksudo

By executing `chown` command to give access of `/root` folder contents for 'test1' user.

After that I am unable to login with my `.ppk` key - `Server refused our key`. How can I get back my root user access?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you log in as another user via putty? After that you could run `su`, enter the root password and should be able to correct your changes. If you have physical or KVM access, you can also "chroot" into the system from an external linux medium, you can quickly find instructions for that on the internet.